# Add li inside nested ul by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an `li` dynamically by jQuery.

```
<div id="myDiv">
 <ul>
   <li>
       hi
   </li>
   <li>
        <ul id="data">
             <li>
             <li>             
        </ul>
   </li>

 </ul>
</div>
```

Add `<li>` where `id = data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add an `<li>` to the `<ul>` which has an ID of 'data', you can use the [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) jQuery function.

```
$('#data').append('<li></li>');
```

If you wanted to create the html jQuery element first so that you can manipulate it, you can do this:

```
var $element = $('<li></li>');
$element.addClass('nestedli');
$('#data').append($element);
```

Comment: Or `$('<li/>').addClass('nestedli').appendTo('#data');`